# How can I return a temporary from my specialized std::max?

Tags: c++, stl

Hallo!
I want to specialize `std::max` for a platform-specific fraction type.

The prototype for the system-specific `max` I want to use looks like this:

```
fract builtin_max(fract a, fract b);
```

My idea for a specialized `std::max` looks like this:

```
template <> inline
const fract& std::max<fract>(const fract& a, const fract& b) {
    return builtin_max(a, b);
}
```

However, the compiler understandably complains about returning a reference to a local temporary. Is there any way I can work around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to do it just like this:

```
fract std::max(fract a, fract b) {
    return builtin_max(a, b);
}
```

Super simple, and works just like I want it :)

Answer (score 3):

You could return a result by value. Then [RVO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization) most likely will take place. In the end you will get behavior as you wanted.

And I'd change `builtin_max` declaration to

```
fract builtin_max(const fract& a, const fract& b);
```

It will help to the compiler to recognize the possibility for RVO.

Finally your `max` will look like:

```
template <> 
fract std::max<fract>(const fract& a, const fract& b) {
    return builtin_max(a, b);
}
```

Comment: @kotlinski Does it mean that fract has no copy constructor? Or your problem is that RVO does not take place?

Comment: It has a copy constructor. My guess is that either RVO does not take place, or the compiler doesn't account for it when emitting warnings.

Comment: If you are to modify the `builtin_max` you might as well have it return a reference --the maximum of two elements IS one of the two elements-- and then everything will fall right in place...

Answer (score 1):

If you can modify the `builtin_max` then the way to go is changing the signature so that it takes two constant references and returns a constant reference (unless the type is small enough that pass-by-value makes sense), and overload for the non-const version of it. Then you can adapt the signatures the easy way: just forward the call.

```
fract const & builtin_max( fract const & lhs, fract const & rhs );
fract & builtin_max( fract & lhs, fract & rhs );

template <>
fract const & std::max( fract const & lhs, fract const & rhs ) {
   return builtin_max( lhs, rhs );
}
template <>
fract & std::max( fract & lhs, fract & rhs ) {
   return builtin_max( lhs, rhs );
}
```

Another simple thing that you can do is not overload `std::max` but rather produce your own `max` function within your namespace. All unqualified uses of `max` that take `fract` values will find your `max` function before they try to use the `std::max` default template. Then again, this will not work for fully qualified calls to `std::max`:

```
namespace x {
   class fract;
   fract max( fract lhs, fract rhs ) { return builtin_max( lhs, rhs ); }
}
// force a link time error if fully qualified std::max is used (undefined)
// instead of silently getting std::max to use < (if it is defined)
// if there is no operator<( fract const &, fract const & ), leave this out
// to get an earlier compile time error
template <> fract const & std::max( fract const &, fract const & );
template <> fract & std::max( fract &, fract & );

int main() {
   using namespace std;
   fract a,b;
   max( a, b );          // x::max
   // std::max( a, b )   // ouch, link time error
}
```